# Why template local variables are not usable in templates when using *ngIf?

Tags: angular

## Part 1: "#test" is undefined when using *ngIf

When referencing an input that can be hidden/"destroyed" (because the `*ngIf` is used and some of the elements are destroyed), the local variable created by the hashtag syntax `#` (`#test` in the example below) does not work, even when the element exists in the page.

The code was:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <button (click)="focusOther(test)">test</button>
    <input #test *ngIf="boolValue" >
    `
})
export class AppComponent { 

  private isVisible = false;

  focusOther(testElement){
    this.isVisible = true;
    alert(testElement);
    testElement.focus();
  }

}
```

The alert displays `undefined`, because nothing is passed to that function.

Is there a solution to make it work?
My goal is to focus an element that will be created.

***Solution given by Mark Rajcok:*** make a directive with an afterViewInit that uses elementRef and calls .focus() on the element.

See this plunker for a working version of part 1:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JmBBHMo1hXLe4jrbpVdv?p=preview

## Part 2 how to re-focus that element after initial creation

Once this problem of "focus after creation" is fixed, I need a way to re-focus() a component, like in "test.focus()" (where #test is the local variable name for the input, but cannot be used like that as I demonstrated before).

***Multiple solutions given by Mark Rajcok***

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179

Comment: I filled up that issue on angular repo since it's a bug if we consider the actual documentation stating "We can reference a local template variable on the same element, on a sibling element, or on any of its child elements.".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As for a solution to the focus problem, you could create an attribute directive, `focusMe`:

```ts
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusMe]'
})
export class FocusDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [FocusDirective],
    template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
      <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>
      <input focusMe *ngIf="isVisible">
    `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  private isVisible = false;
  toggle() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/12SfdZYAaKVVcUzfcl9S?p=preview)</kbd>

**Update 1**: Adding the solution for the re-focus feature:

```ts
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focusMe]'
})
export class FocusMe {
    @Input('focusMe') hasFocus: boolean;
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    ngOnChanges(changes) {
      //console.log(changes);
      if(changes.hasFocus && changes.hasFocus.currentValue === true) {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <button (click)="showInput()">Make it visible</button>
    <input *ngIf="inputIsVisible" [focusMe]="inputHasFocus">
    <button (click)="focusInput()" *ngIf="inputIsVisible">Focus it</button>
    `,
    directives:[FocusMe]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private inputIsVisible = false;
  private inputHasFocus = false;
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  showInput() {
    this.inputIsVisible = true;
  }
  focusInput() {
    this.inputHasFocus = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.inputHasFocus = false, 50);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uiY7Ygt7xsjmPF5xl9ug?p=preview)</kbd>

An alternative to using `setTimeout()` to reset the focus property to `false` would be to create an event/output property on the FocusDirective, and `emit()` an event when `focus()` is called.  The AppComponent would then listen for that event and reset the focus property.

**Update 2**: Here's an alternative/better way to add the re-focus feature, using ViewChild.  We don't need to track the focus state this way, nor do we need an input property on the FocusMe directive.

```ts
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focusMe]'
})
export class FocusMe {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      // set focus when element first appears
      this.setFocus();
    }
    setFocus() {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <button (click)="showInput()">Make it visible</button>
    <input *ngIf="inputIsVisible" focusMe>
    <button (click)="focusInput()" *ngIf="inputIsVisible">Focus it</button>
    `,
    directives:[FocusMe]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(FocusMe) child;
  private inputIsVisible = false;
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  showInput() {
    this.inputIsVisible = true;
  }
  focusInput() {
    this.child.setFocus();
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lLjC7w3gKgDDscIlo7vT?p=preview)</kbd>

**Update 3**: Here's yet another alternative that does not require a directive, which still uses ViewChild, but we access the child via a local template variable rather than an attribute directive (thanks @alexpods for [the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519344/215945)):

```ts
import {Component, ViewChild, NgZone} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Focus test</h1>
    <button (click)="showInput()">Make it visible</button>
    <input #input1 *ngIf="input1IsVisible">
    <button (click)="focusInput1()" *ngIf="input1IsVisible">Focus it</button>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('input1') input1ElementRef;
  private input1IsVisible = false;
  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) { console.clear(); }
  showInput() {
    this.input1IsVisible = true;
    // Give ngIf a chance to render the <input>.
    // Then set the focus, but do this outside the Angualar zone to be efficient.
    // There is no need to run change detection after setTimeout() runs,
    // since we're only focusing an element.
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => { 
      setTimeout(() => this.focusInput1(), 0);
   });
  }
  setFocus(elementRef) {
    elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
  ngDoCheck() {
    // if you remove the ngZone stuff above, you'll see
    // this log 3 times instead of 1 when you click the
    // "Make it visible" button.
    console.log('doCheck');
  }
  focusInput1() {
    this.setFocus(this.input1ElementRef);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qw8KJNSRolZYxShFjpE9?p=preview)</kbd>

**Update 4**: I updated the code in Update 3 to use NgZone so that we don't cause Angular's change detection algorithm to run after the `setTimeout()` finishes.  (For more on change detection, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570122/215945)).

**Update 5**: I updated the code in the above plunker to use Renderer to make it web worker safe. Accessing `focus()` directly on `nativeElement` is discouraged.

```ts
focusInput1() {
  this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
    this.input1ElementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
}
```

I learned a lot from this question.

Comment: I have another problem that appears after that one, how could I give back focus to that input, after initialisation, in a function of the code of the AppComponent that would be triggered? I'll update the plunker once is available. Is there no other solution than creating a custom event inside the directive, and then bind it with the component so when that event is triggered, the focus gets back on the input?

Comment: Great! I like the @ViewChild('input1') use, because I felt that it would really be bad if I had to use a custom directive only for selection. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "web worker safe" ? I don't understand why your Update 3 is "discouraged".

Comment: @Elfayer, see "Use with Caution" section on the ElementRef API page: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html