# Access a local variable from the template in the controller in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am writing a component where I need access to the `<audio controls>` native element. I am doing it like this now by getting it in `ngOnInit()` by using `ElementRef` like this `this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("audio");`

While it works I think it is very unelegant and Angular2 also [warns of the risks when using ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html)..

Is there really no simpler way?

Can I mark it as a local variable with `<audio controls #player>` and somehow access the native element through `this.player` or something similar from the controller?

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'audio-preview',
    template: `
        <audio controls>
            <source [src]="src" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    `
})

export class AudioPreview implements OnInit {

    @Input() src: string;

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        var audioElement = this.getAudioElement();
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', this.src);
    }

    getAudioElement() : HTMLAudioElement {
        return this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("audio");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

1. Use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) to access some element in the view.
2. Use [`[attr.src]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#attribute-binding) to creating binding to 'src' attribute of an element.
3. Use [`Renderer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html) if for some reason you need to change the DOM imperatively.

See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tgxcmel8IligRwCB0ZQS?p=preview).

```ts
import {Component, Input, ViewChild, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'audio-preview',
  template: `
    <audio controls #player [attr.src]="src">
      <source [src]="src" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    `
})
export class AudioPreview {
  @Input() src: string;
  @ViewChild('player') player;

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.player);

    // Another way to set attribute value to element
    // this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.player, 'src', this.src);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I just tried it, and ```<audio controls #player [attr.src]="src">``` seems to work the same as ```<audio controls #player [src]="src">``` ... What's the difference?

Comment: @skovmand [attr.src] create binding to the attribute of an element, using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method of DOM (`element.setAttribute('src', src)`). `[src]` creates binding to  the property of an element (just set it by `element.src = src`)

Comment: I have to ask... where did you learn about using `#player` in the template, and then being able to get a reference to it using `ViewChild('player')`?  (I need to start reading whatever you're reading, because I can't find this kind of info in the Angular docs.  The [ViewChild API page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) doesn't explain this.)

Comment: I found it... eventually.  The [source code for ViewChild](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.0/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata.ts#L1147-L1147) says "Supports the same querying parameters as QueryMetadata, except `descendants`."  The [QueryMetadata API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/QueryMetadata-class.html) explains the different selectors supported.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Actually I don't read some "secret" special books or articles about angular2. Almost all things about angular2 I've learnt from the source codes and their tests. For example [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e44dd85ada181b11be869841da2c157b095ee07/modules/angular2/test/core/linker/query_integration_spec.ts#L341) are the tests for `@Query('something')`.