# Accessing element in an Angular2 JavaScript ES5 component

Tags: javascript, angular, components, ecmascript-5

Edit: As most comments so far give me the TypeScript solution, I feel I need to repeat here: Using JavaScript ES5.

I want to create a canvas component, where I draw data based on a bound property. How can I do this in Angular2 using JavaScript?

My approach with Angular 1 would be to get the element reference in the directive, but I can't find out how this is supposed to be done now.

Here is an approach which seems to work, but I feel like washing my hands after doing this:

```
(function (app) {
    app.DrawingComponent = ng.core
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-drawing',
            template: '<div><canvas id="{{randomId}}"></canvas></div>'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
                this.randomId = "canvas" + Math.random();
            },
            ngAfterViewInit: function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById(this.randomId);
                console.log(canvas);
            }
        });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a local variable from the template in the controller in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517969/access-a-local-variable-from-the-template-in-the-controller-in-angular2)

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to give the TypeScript solution? Tags and title state JavaScript (ES5)

Comment: Ok, I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: check if the answer helps you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only difference between the TS [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517969/access-a-local-variable-from-the-template-in-the-controller-in-angular2) I referenced, and ES5 is the way you call `ViewChild`

While with TS you can use directly the annotation `@ViewChild`, in ES5 you have to use the `queries` parameter in the Component

```
app.DrawingComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'my-drawing',
        template: '<div><canvas #myCanvas></canvas></div>',

        // Check here! This is important!
        queries : {
          myCanvas : new ng.core.ViewChild('myCanvas')
        }
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function () {},
        ngAfterViewInit: function() {
            console.log(this.myCanvas);
        }
    });
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fc4VDUXdTQjHR01S8lj?p=preview) demonstrating the usage. There's another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573219/4933038) that can help you to understand a little bit more its usage.

Answer (score 6):

Add a template variable ('#canvas') to the element

```
template: '<div><canvas #canvas id="{{randomId}}"></canvas></div>'
```

Use `@ViewChild` annotation

```
@ViewChild('canvas') canvas;
```

Implement `AfterViewInit` and and after `ngAfterViewInit()` was called the `canvas` field is initialized with an `ElementRef`. With `canvas.nativeElement` you can access the `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the non-Typescript syntax is, but I'm sure you know that youself.

This is how I've done it:

```
export class Navigation {

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        // elementRef.nativeElement is the actual element
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my actual problem is translating this into JavaScript (ES5)