# Access local variable in Component fails in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I want to get the DOM element and initialize a JSON Editor without using `ElementRef`.

### Code:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'json-editor',
    template: `
        <div #container class="json-editor-container"></div>
    `
})
export class JSONEditorComponent implements OnChanges {
    @ViewChild('container') private container = null;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

No matter how, `this.container` is still null. Which part of code I wrote is wrong?

---

### Solution:

Before you access the `ViewChild` attribute, you must confirm the view has initialized. Also `@VarChild` returns `ElementRef`, if you want to process it further requires DOMElement, please use `nativeElement` attribute which is a `Element`

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'json-editor',
    template: `
        <div #container class="json-editor-container"></div>
    `
})
export class JSONEditorComponent implements OnChanges {
    @ViewChild('container') private container = null;
    private isViewInitialized: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.isViewInitialized = true;
    }

    triggeredFromParentComponentOrWhatever() {
        if (this.isViewInitialized) {
            // Should work
            console.log(this.container.nativeElement);
        }

        // Might not work as view might not initialized
        console.log(this.container.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one you are not actually passing anything to @ViewChild, have you tried adding 'container' to your directives and trying it?  Also you are then instantiating container to null afterwards, which will always make it null.  Also could maybe you explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517969/access-a-local-variable-from-the-template-in-the-controller-in-angular2

Comment: What do you think about the answer?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to do, what it appears the question you are looking at was trying to do was get data from a 'parent' element via input and apply it to the HTML <audio control> element which is his 'child' element.  I am quoting those because I would not exactly call it a parent or child element in that specific case.  Are you just trying to get and submit data?  If you are, this is a backwards way of doing it.  So maybe explain what you are trying to do better please.

Comment: Also here is the plunker put out by Angular2 for how @ViewChild works http://plnkr.co/edit/eNsFHDf7YjyM6IzKxM1j?p=preview

Comment: I want to get the DOM element and initialize a JSON Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `container` in the constructor. It is only set just before `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
ngViewInit() {
  container.nativeElement...
}
```

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.container);
    }`Actually it is still not working

Comment: Do you get any error message? I don't think it makes a difference, but can you try removing `= null`? There might be something else wrong in your app. What do you want to do with the element reference anyway? Can't you do that with binding?

Comment: What fixed it in the end?

Comment: I am sorry actually I made mistake, it works. Sorry for leaving comment without confirmation...