# Angular2: What is the best way to get a reference of a template element

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say I have a component like this in Angular 2.

```
@Component ({
   directives: [Timeline, VideoPlayer],
   template: `<div>
    <span id="myId"></span>
    <videoplayer [mode]="mode"></videoplayer>
    <timeline [mode]="mode"></timeline>
  </div>`,
})
export class VideoEditor {
}
```

How can I get a reference to an element from a template? For instance, how do I get a reference to a `<span>`?

I found two approaches so far:

1) Get a reference using [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

```
export class VideoEditor {    
  constructor (private el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.getElementsBy.....;
  }
}
```

2) Using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

```
export class VideoEditor {  
  @ViewChild(Timeline) timeline: Timeline;  
  ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.timeline;
  }
}
```

3) Using [local template variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#local-vars)

---

1) What I don't like about a first approach is that I need to do `getElementsBy...`-like function.

2) Regarding a second one, I don't know how to get an access to a HTML element, I can only get access to another sub-component. And what if I have more subcomponents of a same type?

3) Local template variable only works within a templates, am I right?

What is the best way to get a reference to a template in Angular 2?
I'd like to have something like React has
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute

```
<input ref="myInput" />
```

---

```
var input = this.refs.myInput;
var inputValue = input.value;
var inputRect = input.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChild('varName')` with a template variable (`<tag #varName>`) to get a specific element when you have more than one of the same type.
You should try to avoid direct access anyway, use bindings instead if possible.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, could you please elaborate a bit more on how to do things using bindings? What do you mean by that?

Comment: This depends on what you actually want to do with the reference to the tag. With bindings I mean `<tag (click)="eventHandler", [prop]="someField">`.

Comment: Let's say I want to focus `<input #keywordInput type="text"/>`. The best way is to do `@ViewChild('keywordInput') keywordInput;` and then`this.keywordInput.nativeElement.focus();` am I right? Sorry this is a bit out of scope of my question.

Comment: I think this only works if the referenced element is a native element (no Angular component/directive. You could build a reusable directive for that similar to the one shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502768/why-angular2-template-local-variables-are-not-usable-in-templates-when-using-ng/34503163#34503163

Comment: I used the @ViewChild('variableName') within the *ngIf and it alway returns undefined. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please create a new question with more code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: How do these "refs" work in angular2 (`#varName`, in this example)? Are they an angular2-specific construct? Are they a shortcut for adding an id? Does it disappear when the component gets compiled to stock HTML? I can't seem to find any official documentation on this.

Comment: Its called template variable. This is never added to the DOM but only used by Angular2. It allows you to reference the DOM element easily from binding expressions in the template and `ViewChild` and `ContentChild` in the compinents class. I don't know where in the docs it's explained more in-depht.

Comment: If anyone does know where the doc for template variables is, please comment. AFAIK the variable can be an id or a class. Can we also just use a tag?

Comment: No, either the name of the template variable or the type of the component or directive.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars

Comment: I get it now - I was thinking of XPaths so thought the # meant id. Thanks.

Comment: Updated URL for @GünterZöchbauer's link: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables