# How setting ng-content by code in 'Angular2'

Tags: angular

How can I set component's ng-content in js with a new component?

I see that the only view composition mentioned in Angular docs is with routings.
But what if I don't want routings in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different approach and succeeded,
I used DynamicComponentLoader to load my component to an element selector .

```
 DynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot(Component1, '#div1, injector);
```

this method load Component1 to an element with id=div1.
DynamicComponentLoader is very imported service that should be in every ng2 book.

Comment: This creates a new component1 instance right? How to move an existing component in view to a specific location?

Comment: Accepted answer does not address the question of "How to set the projected <ng-content> in dynamically created components"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add from within the component, jnject `elementRef: ElementRef` in your components constructor and use `elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(someElement)`.
From the outside just use a different method to get hold of the DOM element and add HTML to it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more. Your question doesn't provide much information either. Maybe you're looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636435/angular2-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-reference-of-a-template-element (or alternatively `@ContentChild`)

Comment: I did what you suggested
`elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(someElement)`
It half worked, the DOM got the new selector in it, but the template is not render.
How I  force the selector rendering?
and secondly:Is there a way to insert the component instead of the component's selector?

Comment: I see, you didn't state what you want to add to the DOM. My approach only works with plain HTML. If you want to add Angular2 components dynamically you need to use DCL.