# Angular2 version RC.6 "directives" inside @Component Error

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-template

I am using Angular2 and have downloaded package.json from the official website. When I am trying to use "directives" inside @Component decorator I am getting this error.

I have attached  my code ERROR:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: string; directives: string; 
}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentMetadataType'.

Object literal may only specific known properties, and 'directives' does not
exist in type 'ComponentMetadataType'.
(property) directives: string
```

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PeopleListComponent } from './people-list/people-list.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>',
 directives: ''   //ERROR //NOT ABLE TO RECOGNIZE
})

export class AppComponent { 
  title = "My title";
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
        {
          "name": "angular2-quickstart",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "scripts": {
            "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
            "lite": "lite-server",
            "postinstall": "typings install",
            "tsc": "tsc",
            "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
            "typings": "typings"
          },
          "license": "ISC",
          "dependencies": {
            "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
            "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
            "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
            "core-js": "^2.4.1",
            "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
            "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
            "systemjs": "0.19.27",
            "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
            "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.18",
            "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
            "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
            "typescript": "^1.8.10",
            "typings":"^1.3.2"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Which version of Angular2 are you using?

Comment: check my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2

Comment: @yurzui In my package.json version is 1.0.0.. Is it the angular verison which I am using?

Comment: You use 2.0.0-rc.6 version of angular2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

simple...

problem is with **`directives: ''`**

as its an array it should be **`directives: [ ]`**

**Update**: In **RC6** **OR** later version, you have **`@NgModule`**. In **RC6** **OR** later version, you have to declare **`pipes`** and **`directives`** that you are gonna use within **`@NgModule`** as shown...

```
import { PeopleListComponent } from './people-list/people-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,PeopleListComponent ],  //<<===here
  providers:    [],      
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

You can remove **`directives:''`** from **`@Component`** of **`AppComponent`**

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: In my package.json version is 1.0.0.. Is it the angular verison which I am using?

Comment: look at the dependencies object... you are using `rc6`

Comment: does your AppComponent require PeopleListComponent ?

Comment: yes I am trying to get the selector from 'PeopleListComponent' so that I could use in my AppComponent..

Comment: Thnx it worked.. I restarted my machine and now its working.. thnx a lot

Answer (score 12):

`directives` and `pipes` inside `@Component` is deprecated from angular RC6. Check my answer on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39410510/692328)

Comment: which error you are getting ? have you tried after removing `directives` from `AppComponent` ?

Comment: I have attached my Error in question.. when I remove directives I am not getting any error.

Comment: then you have to add your component in `declarations` part of your `module` file as per link given in my answer above.

Comment: Thnx it worked.. I restarted my machine and now its working.. thnx a lot