# Angular2: 'directives' property not found in @Component({.....})

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I created a directive to auto-grow a textbox but when i implemented it to the component i'm getting the error.

**myAppComps.ts**

[image]

**NPM RUN BUILD**
[image]

**auto-grow.directives.ts**
[image]

**myAppComps.html**
[image]

package.json:
[image]

Comment: Which version of Angular 2 are you using?

Comment: check the screen shot of package.json i added below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using RC6 and up - you need to use @NgModule to declare the directives (under 'declarations'):

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,PeopleListComponent ],  //<----here
  providers:    [],      
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410591/angular2-version-rc-6-directives-inside-componnet-error)

Comment: i attached the screen shot of package.json file

Comment: Yes - if you're at 2.0.0 - you're in the stable release of Angular 2 - which is above RC 6. Try the NgModule solution above (of course replacing everything with your info)

Comment: i moved it to the NGModule declaration, 
import {AutoGrowDirective} from './comps/auto-grow.directives';
, declarations: [myAppComps, SampleListComp, AutoGrowDirective]
but this time im getting warning..

Comment: same yellow text message in my given screenshot

Comment: in browser im getting: compiler.umd.js:14174Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AutoGrowDirective' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: You have two modules with the same name.

Comment: Alright, i got the solution, actually the warning message is occurred from import statement of angular/core. one is small letter and other is in capital

import {Directive, Renderer, ElementRef} from "@angular/Core";  
import {Component} from "@angular/core";  
  
thats why im getting this warning
Thanks for the above solution