# How to access field validation's errors in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this validation on a field:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
          STRADA
          <input name="street" #street="ngModel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.Address.Street" required/>
          <div *ngIf="street.errors && (street.dirty || street.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
             <div [hidden]="!street.errors.required">
                Strada este obligatorie!
             </div>
          </div>
 </div>
```

How can I access `street.errors` in the typescript side ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `ViewChild()` to get a hold of `#street`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636435/angular2-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-reference-of-a-template-element). This isn't a typescript thing, it's an angular thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Element by using @ViewChild

```
 import { ....., ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

    export class YourComponent.... { 
       @ViewChild('street') streetElement;

        private checkElementStatus(): void { 
           console.log(this.streetElement.errors) 
        }
}
```