# how to use chartjs graph in a *ngFor loop

Tags: css, angular, chart.js

I am having a challenge trying to create a graph for each mat-card in a *ngFor loop. I am setting the canvas like this:

```
 <canvas id="coinLineChart{{coin_index}}" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
```

then create a variable of the id value like this:

```
 let chart_id = `coinLineChart` + `${this.coin_index}`.
```

Then I tried to get the ctx value like this:

```
 coinLineChart = document.getElementById(chart_id);
 const ctx = coinLineChart.getContext("2d");
```

but coinlLineChart turns out to be null.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this? I am using chartjs v3 with Angular 13

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `viewChildren` or viewChild link to canvas tag to have a list of all canvas on looping side

in the html :

```
<canvas #canvas width="200" height="150"></canvas>
```

you have two situation if your component directly have the *ngFor and the canvas element

in the controller

```
@ViewChildren('canvas') canvasList: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

in the function where you need to manipulate canvas

```
 this.canvasList.toArray().forEach(canvas => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //other code on one canvas
});
```

if your canvas is inside a child component you have the ViewChild directive to manipulate it

in the child controller

```
@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef
```

in the child function where you need to manipulate canvas

```
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    //other code on one canvas
```

Comment: This is interesting....but I don't see how it would work? you see my loop (*ngFor) is in my parent who is making multiple calls to <canvas id: "canvas" [graphData]='graphdata' [index]='idx'><canvas>. SO how would another loop inside the child work? because each time I access the child I only have one set of data and the index for that data.

Comment: ok if canvas is in child component you also have element viewChild to refer an html componentn in controller ``@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef``

Comment: the idea is to not have to do a document.get{Seletcor} but have access to html tag in controller side

Comment: i send you a link to another interesting stackoverflow post very near of your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636435/angular2-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-reference-of-a-template-element

Comment: i update my reply in consequencies

Comment: The above didn't work for me...but it pointed me in the right direction. This worked for me: constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { } .....followed by:   this.ctx = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#coinLineChart`)