# Angular2 - ContentChild query does not find nested components

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to set up an Angular2 component that automatically focuses an input element that is inserted via content projection.

The solution I am using is based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503163/1592971). I have an additional requirement that the input element might be nested inside another component. However, I am finding that the `ContentChild` query is not able to detect elements buried deep inside `ng-content` tags.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-feature',
  template: "<input auto-focus>",
  directives: [AutoFocus]
})
export class InnerFeature { }

@Component({
  selector: 'feature',
  template: `
    <div [class.hide]="!show">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Feature {
  @ContentChild(AutoFocus)
  private _autoFocus: AutoFocus;

  private _show: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  get show() {
    return this._show;
  }
  set show(show: boolean) {
    this._show = show;
    if (show && this._autoFocus) {
      setTimeout(() => this._autoFocus.focus());
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="toggleFeature()">Toggle</button>
      <feature [show]="showFeature">
        <inner-feature></inner-feature>
      </feature>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Feature, InnerFeature]
})
export class App {
  showFeature: boolean = false;

  toggleFeature() {
    this.showFeature = !this.showFeature;
  }
}
```

The `_autoFocus` property never gets populated. Contrast that with the case where the `auto-focus` directive is not nested inside another component and it works fine. Is there a way to make this work?

(I have not pasted the code for `AutoFocus` since it's not crucial to this example.)

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8DVXjfrhbBZylSF90DJ?p=preview) for a demo.

**UPDATED** code above to fix a missing directive.

Comment: Seems that's not supported. `ViewQuery` (deprecated) supports `descendants: true` but other similar (non-deprecated features don't seem to support that.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Is there a different solution to this problem? Essentially, I need a generic modal component whose body can be another shared component (such as a common form for adding and editing items), and I want to auto-focus the first element whenever the modal is displayed.

Comment: I guess https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563 will make this easier. Besides that I don't have an idea.

Answer (score 10):

Use `ContentChildren` with `descendants` set to `true`

```
@ContentChildren(AutoFocus, { descendants: true })
```

Comment: This doesn't work with content projection (ngContent) https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/195

Answer (score 2):

Actually i want to invest more time in this problem to find a better solution, but for now i came up with the following which might help you already:

First you have to expose the `AutoFocus` inside your `InnerFeatures` (and you forgot to add `AutoFocus` to your array of `directives`) using `@ViewChild`. This could look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-feature',
  template: "<input auto-focus>",
  directives: [AutoFocus]
})
export class InnerFeature {
  @ViewChild(AutoFocus)
  autoFocus:AutoFocus;
}
```

Then in your parent component `Feature` you could use `@ContentChildren` which returns a `QueryList` of the bound Component (in your case `InnerFeature`).

In your `show` method (or for example in or after `ngAfterContentInit`) you can then access this list of `InnerFeatures`:

```
export class Feature implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(AutoFocus)
  private _autoFocus: AutoFocus;

  @ContentChildren(InnerFeature)
  private _innerFeatures: QueryList<InnerFeature>;

  private _show: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  get show() {
    return this._show;
  }
  set show(show: boolean) {
    this._show = show;
    if (show) {
      setTimeout(() => {
            if (this._autoFocus) {
                this._autoFocus.focus();
            }
            if (this._innerFeatures) {
                this._innerFeatures.map((innerFeature) => {
                    innerFeature.autoFocus.focus();
                });
            }
        });
    }
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this._autoFocus);
    console.log(this._innerFeatures);
  }
}
```

I modified your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IuGxiNEwDs7uvoB05R0i?p=info), so you can test it in action.

Might not be as dynamic as you probably want, but well, i hope it helps anyway.

I will try to come up with a better approach , if there won't be a better answer after the England vs. Island match ;)

**Update**: I updated my code, cause it threw errors when accessing `_results` which is private. Use `map()` instead for the `QueryList`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's helpful, but like you said, not as dynamic as I'd like. I don't want `Feature` to have to know about `InnerFeature`s since there can be several. I'll wait for your answer after the match. :)

Comment: I thought about this a bit. I think that instead of figuring out how to access all instances of `AutoFocus` from all (unknown) and possibly deeply nested childs from the parent component, it probably makes more sense to tackle the problem from another direction. For instance, you  could use a service as a bridge between the directive and the parent components Another approach might be possible with an Event fired from `Feature`.