# Angular ng-content not working with mat-form-field

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

**My goal:**

I'm trying to build a reusable mat-form-field with a clear button.

**How I tried achieving my goal:**

I created a "mat-clearable-input" component and used it like this:

```
<mat-clearable-input>
        <mat-label>Put a Number here pls</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="number_form_control">
    </mat-clearable-input>
```

**mat-clearable-input.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Expected result**:

the ng-content tag takes the label and the input and puts them inside the mat-form-field tag.

**Actual result**:

```
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.js:226)
    at MatFormField._validateControlChild (form-field.js:688)
    at MatFormField.ngAfterContentChecked (form-field.js:558)
    at callHook (core.js:2926)
    at callHooks (core.js:2892)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2844)
    at refreshView (core.js:7239)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8335)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6991)
    at refreshView (core.js:7248)
```

It looks like I'm missing something and I'm not using correctly the ng-content tag.

I wasn't able to locate the documentation for the ng-content tag on the angular website.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER BELOW**

So I tried this suggested method:

```
export class MatClearableInputComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl) _control: MatFormFieldControl<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatFormField) _matFormField: MatFormField;
  // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898533/angular-ng-content-not-working-with-mat-form-field/
  ngOnInit() {
    this._matFormField._control = this._control;
  }

}
```

unfortunately, when I try to use this in a form it still fails with the error "Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl."

Code where i try to use this component in a form:

```
<mat-clearable-input>
    <mat-label>Numero incarico</mat-label>
    <buffered-input matInput formControlName="numero"></buffered-input>
</mat-clearable-input>
```

Repro on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-xypjc5?file=app/clearable-form-field/clearable-form-field.component.html

notice how the mat-form-field features aren't working (no outline, no floating label), also open the console and you'll see the error Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

**EDIT AFTER OPTION 2 WAS POSTED**

I tried doing this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput hidden>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-form-field>
```

It works, but then when i added a mat-label to my form field, like this:

```
<mat-clearable-input>
        <mat-label>Numero incarico</mat-label>
        <buffered-input matInput formControlName="numero"></buffered-input>
    </mat-clearable-input>
```

the label is never floating and it's just staying there as a normal span the whole time.

So i tried assigning to the `this._matFormField._control._label` the content child with the label but that didn't work because _label is private and there is no setter for it.

It looks like I'm out of luck and this can't be done in Angular without going through a lot of effort.

If you have any further ideas feel free to fork the stackblitz and try!

**Edit after @evilstiefel answer**

the solution works only for native `<input matInput>`.
When I try replacing that with my custom input component, it doesn't work anymore.

Working setup:

```
<mat-form-field appClearable>
    <mat-label>ID incarico</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="id">
</mat-form-field>
```

Same setup but with my custom "buffered-input" component (not working :( )

```
<mat-form-field appClearable>
    <mat-label>ID incarico</mat-label>
    <buffered-input matInput formControlName="id"></buffered-input>
</mat-form-field>
```

The console logs this error when I click on the clear button:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngControl' of undefined
    at ClearableDirective.clear (clearable.directive.ts:33)
    at ClearButtonComponent.clearHost (clearable.directive.ts:55)
    at ClearButtonComponent_Template_button_click_0_listener (clearable.directive.ts:47)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14293)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14328)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27126)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
```

Comment: If you want to use a component inside a `mat-form-field` (in this case, to put `mat-clearable-input` inside it) it must implement `MatFormFieldControl` interface. Take a look at [the docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control) to see how to do it.

Comment: @julianobrasil thanks, but that's not the problem: in the code snippet in the question, I'm using an input tag with the matInput directive, so that should work inside mat-form-field.
I'm not creating custom components.
Also keep in mind that this code works if I don't use ng-content and I just put the input tag there by hand

Comment: Maybe a stackblitz would be helpful

Comment: one question: what should it look like?

Comment: @AndreEirico like the first example of this page https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is using a directive to implement the behaviour.

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ComponentFactory,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ContentChild,
  Directive,
  Injector,
  Input,
  Optional,
  SkipSelf,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';


@Directive({
  selector: '[appClearable]'
})
export class ClearableDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl) matInput: MatFormFieldControl<any>;
  @Input() appClearable: TemplateRef<any>;
  private factory: ComponentFactory<ClearButtonComponent>;

  constructor(
    private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
  ) {
    this.factory = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ClearButtonComponent);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.appClearable) {
      this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.appClearable);
    } else {
      this.vcr.createComponent(this.factory, undefined, this.injector);
    }
  }

  /**
   * This is used to clear the formControl oder HTMLInputElement
   */
  clear(): void {
    if (this.matInput.ngControl) {
      this.matInput.ngControl.control.reset();
    } else {
      this.matInput.value = '';
    }
  }
}

/**
 * This is the markup/component for the clear-button that is shown to the user.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-clear-button',
  template: `
  <button (click)="clearHost()">Clear</button>
  `
})
export class ClearButtonComponent {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() private clearDirective: ClearableDirective) { }

  clearHost(): void {
    if (this.clearDirective) {
      this.clearDirective.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

This creates a directive called `appClearable` and an optional Component for a fallback-layout. Make sure to add the component and the directive to the `declarations`-array of your module. You can either specify a template to use for providing the user-interface or just use the `ClearButtonComponent` as a one-size-fits-all solution. The markup looks like this:

```html
<!-- Use it with a template reference -->
<mat-form-field [appClearable]="clearableTmpl">
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="exampleInput">
</mat-form-field>

<!-- use it without a template reference -->
<mat-form-field appClearable>
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="exampleInput2">
</mat-form-field>

<ng-template #clearableTmpl>
  <button (click)="exampleInput.reset()">Marked-Up reference template</button>
</ng-template>
```

This works with and without a ngControl/FormControl, but you might need to adjust it to your use-case.

Comment: This is working but only when i use it like this.


<mat-form-field appClearable>
        <mat-label>ID incarico</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="id">
    </mat-form-field>


If I try using it on a custom form control, it doesn't work. I'll do another edit to the question showing the problem

Comment: Ah. It will if you change the type of the `@ContentChild()` from `MatInput` to `MatFormFieldControl`. My version initially only worked with native elements like `input` or `textarea`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you also happen to also know how to put the clear button HTML INSIDE of the mat form field instead of as a sibling? 
I need the button to be a child of the mat form field so that I can position it relative to the mat form field.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093727 for a strategy. Unfortunately, the `viewContainerRef` for the ContentChild cannot be called the same way as in my example. You can get it to work by accessing native elements, but I would avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Option 1 does not work for new angular versions because `@ViewChild()` returns undefined in `ngOnInit()` hook. Another hack is to use a dummy `MatFormFieldControl` -

**Option 2**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput hidden>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Edit**:

That error is thrown because `MatFormField` component queries the child content using `@ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl)` which does not work if you use nested `ng-content` ([MatFormField also uses content projection](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/57e32e9acf35321d5aa852a4d72097f33c43e88e/src/material-experimental/mdc-form-field/form-field.html)).

**Option 1** (deprecated)

Below is how you can make it work -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-clearable-input',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-form-field>
  `
})
export class FieldComponent implements OnInit { 
    @ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl) _control: MatFormFieldControl<any>;
    @ViewChild(MatFormField) _matFormField: MatFormField;

    ngOnInit() {
        this._matFormField._control = this._control;
    }
}
```

Please checkout [this stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-rewh7v?file=app/app.component.html). Also, there is [this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411) created in `github` already.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this is working, just one more question: why / how does this work?

Comment: That's because `angular material` could not query `MatFormFieldControl` via `ng-content` by itself during `AfterContentInit` (i'm not sure why). Take a look at the `form-field.ts` file from `angular material` where the error is thrown and see the call hierarchy. In the above solution, we are doing the same thing explicitly which `MatFormField` component does to get `MatFormFieldControl` - https://github.com/angular/components/blob/57e32e9acf35321d5aa852a4d72097f33c43e88e/src/material-experimental/mdc-form-field/form-field.ts#L451.

Comment: One thing to note is that `MatFormField` component also uses content projection and maybe it's not able to query `MatFormFieldControl` because of multiple content projection down the line. I'm just guessing - https://github.com/angular/components/blob/57e32e9acf35321d5aa852a4d72097f33c43e88e/src/material-experimental/mdc-form-field/form-field.html

Comment: I think I'm right. `@ContentChild()` does not work for nested content projections. Since angular material is also using projection, it fails to find the MatFormFieldControl if you also use content projection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060342/angular2-contentchild-query-does-not-find-nested-components/44431500

Comment: Perfect answer, maybe you could add that to the answer. It looks like it's something applicable to a lot of other cases. Thank you!

Comment: So I've tried this in my actual project and it's not working. It's still giving the error mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. I'm updating the question because the problem isn't solved for some reason ;(

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem on stackBlitz.com?

Comment: good idea i will try reproducing on stackblitz right now.

Comment: i've updated the answer with a link to a reproduction on stackblitz.com
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-xypjc5?file=app/clearable-form-field/clearable-form-field.component.html

Comment: Sure.. will take a look

Comment: Updated my answer. The original solution does not work for angular versions > 5. There can be more workarounds but using a dummy field is the easiest one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort; unfortunately, it looks like even with the dummy input tag, I'm still running into issues for example when trying to use a label along with my input. I'll update the question but basically, it looks like this can't be done at all

Comment: I feel the same. Let's not waste more brain. And there are other similar questions and answers already. I'll delete this one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46705101/3503019

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular 14 in 2022, the [issue for the MatFormField](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411) has been closed against [angular/angular#37319](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37319), without a solution. If you need this to work, the following seems to be the best solution that's possible now to use `<ng-content>` with `mat-form-field`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input-wrapper',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <!-- make sure this is destroyed so all bindings/subscriptions are removed-->
      <input *ngIf="isBeforeViewInit$$ | async" hidden matInput />
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
});
class MyInputWrapper implement AfterViewInit {
  isBeforeViewInit$$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  @ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl) matFormControl: MatFormFieldControl<unknown>;
  @ViewChild(MatFormField) matFormField: MatFormField;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // replace the reference to the dummy control
    this.matFormField._control = this.matFormControl;
    // force the form field to rebind everything to the actual control
    this.matFormField.ngAfterContentInit();
    this.isBeforeViewInit$$.next(false);
  }
}
```