# Angular 2 Focus in a input of a modal

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using modals in a angular project and I need to focus one field inside a modal.This field is part of a **@component**:

> Autocomplete.html

```
<div #autocomplete>
    <input #input required>
    <ul class="list" *ngIf="isShow()">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And

> Autocomplete.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'autocomplete',
    templateUrl: './autocomplete.html'
})
export class Autocomplete 
{
}
```

This modal is call from another element of the same **@component** in the *main view* and when I clic in the first input, the modal has already been completely rendered so the `ngAfterViewInit interface` no help me.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some delay before set the input get focus. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530535/1702774).