# How to set auto focus in mat-select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my angular project have angular material and use mat-select. Mat-select is the first element for my form in my case set auto focus while page was loaded successfully but I wasn't able to set auto focus on mat-select. Anyone can help me to find the way to set auto focus in mat-select.

```
@ViewChild("name") nameField: ElementRef;

ngOninit() {
  this.nameField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

html

```
<div>
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="nameField" #name>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</div>
```

Comment: `[focused]="true"`?

Comment: You have to use a directive for that purpose. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729559/7630248

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Material input focus not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504628/angular-2-material-input-focus-not-working)

Comment: Please include the code you've tried, here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I still can't figure it out why you picked up my answer and put inside the question

Comment: you just want to focus select or focus and open when loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to focus select element on load. If this is the case, your code is perfectly fine, you just need to move focus logic in to another life cycle event which is

> ngAfterViewInit

HTML:

```
<mat-select #fff>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS:

```
export class SelectOverviewExample  implements AfterViewInit{
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  @ViewChild("fff", {static: false}) nameField: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.nameField.focused = true;
  }
}
```

Find working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focus-select-afterload). You can see select is highlighted. comment code inside ngAfterViewInit() and see this difference.

Comment: Thanks @Harshad vekariya , it's working fine as expected

Comment: How it works for ngFor.. I want to focus 0 index  mat dropdown

Answer (score 10):

HTML :

```html
<mat-select #someRef >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items;" [value]="item">
    {{item.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

.ts :
make sure you import **MatSelect**

```js
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';
```

```js
@ViewChild('someRef') someRef: MatSelect;


ngOnInit() {
    if(this.someRef) this.someRef.focus();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: best to add a truthy check on `this.someRef`

Comment: Using `ElementRef` on Angular 9 did not work to me, but `MatSelect` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As this is the First hit that shows up on Google I'll provide what I found:

**Note that I did this specifically for a `mat-select` as there is no *real* inner html element that the reference could be attached to**.

What I found works is getting a reference to the element through `view-child` and then calling

```
reference._elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
```

Hope this helps at least someone :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use default angular attribute for autofocus

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="xyz" cdkFocusInitial>
        <mat-option value="abc">Abc</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Caveat: `cdkFocusInitial` doesn't do anything on its own. It will only work inside an element with the `cdkTrapFocus` directive on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MatSelect` on `viewChild` to access focused attribute, then onInit set it to true.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #mySelect [(ngModel)]="nameField">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">{{ option.name }} 
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and ts file import `import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';`

```
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';

export class SelectExample implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSelect) mySelect: MatSelect;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mySelect.focused = true;
  }  
}
```

Comment: This in incorrect AFAIK. It sets the style to `focused` but this not actually focuses the element!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the focus on `OnInit`

ts:

```
 options2 = ['A', 'B'];

  @ViewChild('name')
  nameField: MdSelect;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.nameField.open();
    }, 0);
  }
```

html:

```
<div>
<md-select [(ngModel)]="nameField" #name>
    <md-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">{{ option }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

EDIT: Sorry, I think you can not get the *nativeElement* from `mat-select` and `md-select`. You need to get the object and call `open()`.
Workning project [here in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I already tried that way but its not working its only working for input elements not for mat-select

Answer (score 0):

First, let’s create the Directive
**auto-focus.directive.ts**

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
     selector: '[autoFocus]' }) export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {

     public constructor(private el: ElementRef) {     
     }

     public ngAfterContentInit() {
         setTimeout(() => {
             this.el.nativeElement.focus();
         }, 500);
     }
}
```

Next we need to tell our AppModule that this new directive exists and to declare it for availability by updating our  app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AutoFocusDirective
    ]
})
```

Now you can use it in a component template:
**app.component.html**

```
<div> Autofocus? <input appAutoFocus> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can adapt this example to your own project. Clicking on the button becomes focus.

[focusing on form elements the Angular way](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-focus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[show more](https://codeburst.io/focusing-on-form-elements-the-angular-way-e9a78725c04f)

Comment: [Providing a link to an answer is not a good way of answering a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/194720). Please include the relevant code, if the site's license allows, here on Stack Overflow. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable snippet.

Comment: I already tried that way but its not working its only working for input elements not for mat-select