# Angular set focus to select element on page load

Tags: html, angular

I can set focus to an input field, but not a select.  What am I missing?

This works:

```
    <input matInput formControlName="name" required maxlength="100" id="elementFocus" appElementFocus="true" />
```

This does not

```
    <mat-select formControlName="countryId" required id="elementFocus" appElementFocus="true">
```

Here's the entire section that exists now, and when the page loads, the 2nd form element (Name) has focus.  I need the select to have focus.

```
    <mat-card-content>

      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="container">

        
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Countries</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="countryId" #countrySelectRef required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.id"
              >{{ c.name }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(f.countryId)">{{
            getErrorMessage(f.countryId)
          }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="name" required maxlength="100" />
          <mat-hint align="end">{{ f.name.value.length }} / 100</mat-hint>
          <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(f.name)">{{
            getErrorMessage(f.name)
          }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

    </mat-card-content>
```

.ts code (narrowed down to all that is relevant, I think).

```
  @ViewChild(MatSelect) countrySelectRef: MatSelect;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private matDialog: MatDialog,
    private readonly countryService: CountryService,
    private readonly stateService: StateService,
    private messageService: UIMessageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const paramId = this.getParam('id');
    this.isAdd = !paramId
    this.id = !paramId ? uuid() : paramId
    this.heading = this.isAdd ? `Add ${this.headingName}` : `Edit ${this.headingName}`
    this.initForm();
    if (!this.isAdd) {
      this.patchForm()
    }
  }
  

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    if (this.countrySelectRef) {
      this.countrySelectRef.focus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593925/how-to-set-auto-focus-in-mat-select?

Comment: Do you mean autofocus? Because from your code, it looks like it should focus the select, but since you are not using it inside a `mat-form-field` directive, the select is not being styled properly, hence, the focus style is not being applied.

Comment: I'm really trying here to make sense of what you are saying.  I've relatively new to angular, and I cannot get me .ts backend file to actually figure out what #countryidForSelect is.  I've given that mat-select the # directive: <mat-select formControlName="countryId" required #countryidForSelect>.  But this line, that I just added to the .ts ngOnInit method, won't compile.  if(this.countryidForSelect) this.countryidForSelect.focus();

Comment: @MishaMashina no that doesn't help, but that's likely because I don't understand the answer yet.  Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Show us the TS code as well as the template. The `#countryIdForSelect` in the template is called a **template variable**, also called local reference, and while you can access them from the component (TS file), you need to perform an extra step, you need to use the decorator `ViewChild`. If you share your TS code we can show you.

Comment: @DavidFontes I just made sure that the .html and .ts sections are the ones you want to see.  Thank you for being willing to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set auto focus in mat-select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593925/how-to-set-auto-focus-in-mat-select)

Comment: @ChrisW. no it doesn't.  I'm trying to figure out why.  But I'm getting this error when compiling: "Error: src/app/feature/states/states-edit/states-edit.component.ts:57:29 - error TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a problem, in the sense that it can trigger a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error, but even with that error, it should work fine. Your code and the error message, described in your comment, don't match up and may indicate that the issue is elsewhere.

I do provide an alternative, which hopefully, will solve your problem. You need to add the `A11yModule` to the `imports` array of the module that declare the component that use that template.

**Template**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus>
    <mat-label>Countries</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="countryId" #countrySelectRef required
    cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture
    cdkTrapFocus="false">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.id">
            {{ c.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(f.countryId)">
        {{ getErrorMessage(f.countryId) }}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Note the 2 (with 3 inputs in total) directives added:

- **cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus**: considers an element focused if it or any of its children are focused
- **cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture**: Whether the directive should automatically move focus into the trapped region upon initialization and return focus to the previous activeElement upon destruction.
- **cdkTrapFocus="false"**: If this value is true, it will trap the focus on that directive indefinitely.

Ref: [Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/api)