# Getting keyboard focus on modal once open without JavaScript

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, wai-aria

Once I click on a button on the main page a modal opens up with a list of items for the user to select from. The content within my modal is not getting focus when the modal is opened instead when I press tab - I see it tabbing through the rest of the items on the homepage (background) before actually getting into the modal.

How can I get my modal content to get focus once open rather than having to tab through the main page before reaching the modal?

Here is my code for the modal:

```
<div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog override">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="section">
                <header class="section-header">
                    <button tabindex="0" class="pull-right win-icon win-icon-Clear" (click)="close()" title="close-dialog"></button>
                </header>
                <div class="section-body">
                    <ng-content select=".modal-body"></ng-content>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my method for opening the modal:

```js
 public open() {
        this.modal.open();
        this.myService.getUsers()
            .subscribe((data: ClassRoster[]) => {
                this.classData = data;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Without JavaScript

Give your button the `autofocus` attribute:

```
<div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog override">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="section">
                <header class="section-header">
                    <button autofocus tabindex="0" class="pull-right win-icon win-icon-Clear" (click)="close()" title="close-dialog"></button>
                </header>
                <div class="section-body">
                    <ng-content select=".modal-body"></ng-content>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason that you have to do it to the button and cannot apply it straight to the div because [autofocus only works on `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autofocus.asp). It's not ideal, but it works.

## With JavaScript

Make your modal opening function like this:

```
 public open() {
        this.modal.open();
        document.querySelector('.modal').focus();
        this.myService.getUsers()
            .subscribe((data: ClassRoster[]) => {
                this.classData = data;
            });
    }
```

Comment: I got it to work based on your suggestion but i noticed that when i open the dialog the focus goes to the closing button and if i was to close the dialog and open it again i don't get the focus on the button anymore... why is that?

Comment: @bluePearl It is because the button has already been autofocused on, and cannot be re-focused automatically without JavaScript.

Comment: and if i where to add javascript how much of an impact/code would it be? I have included my modal open method in my post.

Comment: adding this line i get an error message stating: Property `.getQuerySelector` does not exist on type `Document`. Did you mean `querySelectorAll()`
When i tried using querySelectorAll i then get `focus()` underlined as an error stating: `Property focus does not exist on type NodeListOf<Element>`

Comment: @bluePearl Sorry, I made a mistake - I've updated the answer, it should work now.

Comment: Also don't forget to upvote if you like the answer :)

Comment: now i get an underlined error for `focus()` stating: Propery focus does not exist on type Element.

Comment: Is the function in JavaScript running on the page?

Comment: This is when i compile the code that i am seeing this error. As for what i am using i am using TypeScript

Comment: Compile or run in the browser? Maybe the compiler just doesn't like it for some reason. It should work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728939/5374560)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the autofocus attribute

Comment: I tried adding autofocus to my outermost div but i am still not getting focus on it when the modal opens - i still have to tab through the rest of the page before reaching modal content.

Answer (score 2):

The **autofocus** attribute is a boolean attribute.
When present, it specifies that an  element should automatically get focus when the page loads.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The autofocus attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue that i am facing with this is i have refresh the page after each use to use it again after initial load